# How to install ssl of lets encrypt in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, ssl, lets-encrypt

I tried to install ssl using ssh server in Google cloud but showing your directory not available, kindly guide me how to install ssl, supporting software is Apache 2 debin buster

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are running commands from sudo user
Login from SSH and try running these commands

```
apt-get install python3-certbot-apache -y
certbot --apache -d wordpress.example.com
```

If you are facing any issue with this, then please provide the error with a screenshot.

Regards